# reading an IsolatedStorageFile in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, io, isolatedstorage

I would like to take a file in isolatedstorage and convert it to a filestream for reading.

how do I do this in code?

Answer (score 2):

You mean an [IsolatedStorageFileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream.aspx)? Your question provides the answer already.

Edit: Just saw that the msdn page for the silverlight version of this class doesn't provide an example. The link points to the "normal" implementation though and explains exactly how to use it.